# run linux grep command from python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, grep, subprocess

I know there are posts already on how to use subprocess in python to run linux commands but I just cant get the syntax correct for this one. please help. This is the command I need to run...

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Ok this is what I have at the moment that gives a syntax error...

```
import subprocess
self.ip = subprocess.Popen([/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'])
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Running the [useless grep](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) in Python makes no sense at all.  Python is superbly equipped to perform the field extraction natively.

Comment: @tripleee you don't need the external process at all here. Call `get_ip_address('eth1')` from [How can i get the IP Address of eth0 in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24196932/4279)

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been gone over many, many times before; but here is a simple pure Python replacement for the inefficient postprocessing.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
eth1 = subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/ifconfig', 'eth1'], stdout=PIPE)
out, err = eth1.communicate()
for line in out.split('\n'):
    line = line.lstrip()
    if line.startswith('inet addr:'):
        ip = line.split()[1][5:]
```

Comment: @whoopididoo: `ip = re.search(br'inet addr:(\S+)', subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig', 'eth1'])).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to construct the pipe in Python (rather than reverting to `Shell=True`, which is more difficult to secure).

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

# Do `which` to get correct paths
GREP_PATH = '/usr/bin/grep'
IFCONFIG_PATH = '/usr/bin/ifconfig'
AWK_PATH = '/usr/bin/awk'

awk2 = Popen([AWK_PATH, '{print $1}'], stdin=PIPE)
awk1 = Popen([AWK_PATH, '-F:', '{print $2}'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=awk2.stdin)
grep = Popen([GREP_PATH, 'inet addr'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=awk1.stdin)
ifconfig = Popen([IFCONFIG_PATH, 'eth1'], stdout=grep.stdin)

procs = [ifconfig, grep, awk1, awk2]

for proc in procs:
    print(proc)
    proc.wait()
```

It'd be better to do the string processing in Python using `re`. Do this to get the stdout of `ifconfig`.

```
from subprocess import check_output

stdout = check_output(['/usr/bin/ifconfig', 'eth1'])
print(stdout)
```

Comment: You are lacking the significant `-F :` option on `awk1`.  It causes Awk to split the input on colons, instead of whitespace.  Of course, the whole pipeline could be simply `awk '/inet addr:/ { print substr($2, 6) }'`

Comment: @tripleee I've added the -F: option.

Comment: you should close the pipes in the parent otherwise you may hang child processes. Or [start the last command first and pass its stdin pipe to stdout of the preceding command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164238/4279).

Comment: @PeterSutton: you should get the output from `awk2` (set stdout=PIPE, call communicate()). You still should close the pipes (call communicate() instead of wait(), to avoid relying on the garbage collection to free file descriptors in the parent).